# featherjs mongodb document count query

Tags: mongoose, feathersjs

How to get the collection count in featherjs using feather-mongoose ?  Like we do find. Is there any count keyword for that?
app.service("customers").find()

Answer (score 0):

The `total` always returns the count and setting the [`$limit` query parameter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html#limit) to 0 will execute a fast count-only query. For example the following will return the number of unread messages:

```
const { total } = await app.service('customers').find({
  query: { read: false }
});
```